# GNU GRUB v2.06 auto iterates through menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

GNU GRUB v2.06 loops through OS menu, this stops the countdown which autoloads Ubuntu.  It's as if I have a keyboard plugged in and I am pressing the down arrow continuously. But no keys are being pressed in reality.

How do I make the menu stop looping through the options?

Comment: I am getting this behavior on a Lenovo ThinkCentre M70q Gen 2 Tiny Desktop! Every second or two (the interval is random), the up arrow key is pressed, rapidly, but with erratic short delays between these presses as well. But there's no keyboard attached. The selection always returns to the top choice. Then the cycle repeats. Until I hear back from Lenovo support, I will just plug in an old keyboard. With a keyboard attached, the phantom key presses do not happen and GRUB will allow Ubuntu to boot normally.

Answer (score 2):

Grub auto looping through menu was fixed by resetting the BIOS back to default, then updating to the latest version.

Motherboard: Asus rog maximus XIII hero